# How to search a directory for all text files

Tags: c++, windows, filenames, filepath

this is my first official post here, so let's begin:
I need to make a method in my class Searcher to find all the text files in a directory and add them to a vector.
I figured, when I find another directory, to call the function recursively so that I could do my search for the .txt files in that directory aswell..and so on.
So here is how I did it:

```
void IndexIt(string direktorij) {
    string pom(direktorij);
    DIR* dir = opendir(direktorij.c_str());

    if(dir==NULL) {
        cout<<"Ne mogu otvoriti direktorij!";
        return;
    }
    struct dirent *file;
    while ((file = readdir(dir))!=NULL) {
        string filename(file->d_name);

        if (filename.substr(filename.length()-4)== ".txt") {
            AddTheFilenameInVector(filename);  //made a simple method to add the filename in a vector
        } //so I could save it for later use

        string filepath = pom + "\\" + filename;
        try {
            struct stat filedata;

            stat (filepath.c_str(), &filedata);
            if (S_ISDIR(filedata.st_mode)) {
                IndexIt(filepath);

            }

        }
        catch(...) {
            int b(2);
            cout<<" "<<b*2;
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to build it, I just get the caught exceptions in the try-catch block. I must be doing something wrong and I suspect on my recursive calling of IndexIt(filepath).
I've tried with other alternatives such as

```
string directory;
const size_t last_slash_idx = filename.rfind('\\');
if (std::string::npos != last_slash_idx) {
    directory = filename.substr(0, last_slash_idx);
}
```

to get the filepath, also didn't resolve my issue.
I hope I explained it well enough.

I forgot to say that any libraries except those bellow are not allowed.
    `#include <iostream>`
    `#include <vector>`
    `#include <string>`
    `#include <stdio.h>`
    `#include <string.h>`
    `#include <sys/stat.h>`
    `#include <sys/types.h>`
    `#include <dirent.h>`
    `#include <fstream>`

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code here.

Comment: why you are not using [boost filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/tutorial.html) ?

Comment: To expand on what @behzad.nouri said, boost filesystem is on it's way to becoming standard. It makes this sort of thing much easier. Use it.

Comment: File and directory processing are platform dependent, so to clear up and confusion, please edit your post or tags to show your platform (Windows, Linux, embedded, mobile, etc.).

Comment: Use forward slash, '/', as directory separators.  The backslash, '\', may cause problems when not escaped.

Comment: Forward slash doesn't seem to be my problem here.
I experimented with my main now and when I try to Search inside a folder(which only contains 1 .txt file) by typing e.g. _D://test//_  or  _D:/test/_ the program just crashes with a message: **This application has requested the runtime to terminate it in a unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information.**